# How to get line numbers of a different window

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, line-numbers

I would like to get these line numbers of a different window without moving to that window.

```
line('w0')
line('w$')
line('.')
line('$')
```

As for the first two, we can use `getwininfo([{winid}])` which returns a list including 'topline' and 'botline'. Is there any function or some workaround as for the last two?

Answer (score 2):

As a partial answer, for `line('.')`, you can get the buffer number associated with a window with `winbufnr({nr})` (carefull to pass the window *number* and not the window *id*) then pass it to `getbufinfo([{expr}])` and get the `lnum` entry :

```
getbufinfo(winbufnr({nr}))[0]['lnum']
```

Thanks to @Luc Hermitte, we can get the last line number with

```
len(getbufline(winbufnr({nr}), 1, '$')
```

which gets all the lines of the buffer as a list of strings and returns its length.

### Old original answer

Can't tell how to get `line('$')` without moving to the actual window. But we could achieve it with a function that restores the current and previous visited window, than get any `line({expr})` :

```
function! WindowLine(winnr, expr)
    let curr_window = winnr()
    let prev_window = winnr('#')
    exec a:winnr . 'wincmd w'
    let line = line(a:expr)
    exec prev_window . 'wincmd w'
    exec curr_window . 'wincmd w'
    return line
endfunction
echo WindowLine(2, '$')
```

Comment: With `len(getbufline(winbufnr({nr}), 1, '$')`  we can obtain the number of the last line in a given buffer. It will be a lot more efficient than any solution that switches context (and that could also trigger autocommands)

Answer (score 2):

patch 8.1.1418 introduced [:h win_execute()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#win_execute%28%29) :

```
call win_execute(winid, 'let l:num_lines = line("$") | let l:current_line = line(".")')
```

It's fast, it has no window related side effect.

Comment: Thank you. win_execute() can be used not only for line() but also other window local functions without changing the window.